# Reddit Api Error trying to get reddit self text via snoocore node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, node-webkit, reddit

I'm tryng to get the self.text on a post and using this route:

```
reddit('/r/Denmark/comments/2jc5yk/how_to_live_in_denmark.json').listing({ 
        context: 1,
        limit: 10,
        sort: 'hot',
    })
    .then(function(result) { 
        console.log(result);
    });
```

I have also tried using `.get()`, without `.json` and without `/how_to_live_in_denmark` but still the same error.

When I input the route in my browser, I get the desired JSON.

The error i get:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid path provided! This endpoint does not exist. Make sure that your call matches the routes that are defined in Reddit's API documentation
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update: 2015-02-09**

Snoocore now accepts URLS's with embedded values and does not require placeholders if you do not wish to use them.

---

I'm the creator of this API wrapper. I'll have to monitor StackOverflow a little bit more to catch these quicker. Feel free to open new issues on GitHub as well when you get stuck on something for a quicker response!

It looks like you are trying to call this endpoint:

[GET /r/[subreddit]/comments/article](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api#GET_comments_%7Barticle%7D)

Basically anything that is in brackets is optional in Snoocore, and anything in *italics* is an URL parameter that you will need to define placeholders for in the call (using $parameter). More information on this can be read in the [documentation](http://tsenior.com/snoocore/basicUsage.html) (feel free to ask questions or improve upon the documentation if it isn't clear!)

So in your case, you will want to do this:

```
reddit('/r/$subreddit/comments/$article').get({
  $subreddit: 'Denmark',
  $article: '2jc5yk',
  context: 1,
  limit: 10,
  sort: 'hot'
}).done(function(result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

Note that instead of defining the url parameters in the call, the are now referenced by `$subreddit` and `$article` respectivly.

Note that comments are *not* a listing, and therefore can't use the [listings interface](http://tsenior.com/snoocore/listings.html) as you tried to do in your question.